# How do I have a Tableview go to another tableview

Tags: iphone, xcode, uitableview

Right now I have an indexed tableview that goes to a detail view but i want it to go to another tableview then a detail view.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 2):

Use a UINavigationController with the first table view as its root view controller.

Implement the `tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath:` method of the table view's delegate to create the second table view (from a nib or programmatically, doesn't matter, as long as it's an instance of UITableViewController), then call the navigation controller's `pushViewController:animated:` method with the new controller.

Then, from the second controller, present your detail view as you are doing so already.

See also:

- [Using Navigation Controllers](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/UsingNavigationControllers/UsingNavigationControllers.html)
- [Navigating a Data Hierarchy with Table Views](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/TableView_iPhone/TableViewAndDataModel/TableViewAndDataModel.html)
- [SimpleDrillDown](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/prerelease/library/samplecode/SimpleDrillDown/index.html) sample project (may require registration)

Answer (score 0):

The same way you would go to a detail view, but instead of transitioning to a view transition to a TableView.